# Embedded images in HTML email

Tags: html, vb.net, image, email

I have a text file (htmlText containing an HTML message to be sent out in a mass mailing.   The text is marked up with my images using HTML code like

```
<img src='cid:imgheader'/>
```

I have followed example after example of how to use the LinkedResource in my VB code like

```
Dim imgHeader As String = "header.jpg"
Dim lnkHeader As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource(imgHeader)
lnkHeader.ContentId = "imgHeader"
Dim av As AlternateView =   AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlText, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)

av.LinkedResources.Add(lnkHeader)
```

and yet, the images are received as attachments and are not embedded in the email body as expected.   What am I missing or doing wrong?   My images are stored in the executable path of the program which is a console application.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I can see is that you are passing in just the file name to your `LinkedResource` it needs to be the actual location of the image and ***not*** just the file name.

Give this a shot....

```
 Dim imageLink As New LinkedResource(PATHTOIMAGE)
 imageLink.ContentId = "myImage"
 Dim altView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body><img src=cid:myImage/><br>" & htmlText & "</body></html>", Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
 altView.LinkedResources.Add(imageLink)
```

Append it to the body of the mail...

```
 YOURMAILMESSAGEOBJECT.AlternateViews.Add(altView)
 YOURMAILMESSAGEOBJECT.IsBodyHtml = True
```

Comment: I did as you indicated by adding the physical path of the image including the image name on the LinkedResource method but I am still not getting any images in the email that is sent.  It shows as broken image in the email.   The image is stored on the server where the console application is running.  When I examine the html element in the web mail display, it prefixes http:// to the cid:myimage

Comment: All the images that I am using are showing as attachments and not embedded in the HTML message.

Comment: Is there any other suggestions because I am my wit's end trying to solve this.

Comment: You said it is showing as a broken image. What are you viewing the email from? GMail, Outlook etc what email client? Also can you right click on the image to give you other options? It may just be a security thing.

Comment: I am testing using both web mail and Outlook.   I am at a point where the images render correctly in webmail but in Outlook, only the last image shows.   I had been missing a statement to define the image type in my LinkedResource statement but it did not fix the problem for Outlook.

Comment: Just tested in gmail and not receiving the images there either.   I am sending my message on MS Exchange server.   Could that be the problem?

Comment: That isn't the problem... I just tested this on Exchange, Gmail and Yahoo and it worked just fine. I did see that in my example above that I closed out the image tag wrong... Instead of **/><br>** it should be `><br>`... Try this `Dim altView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body><img src=cid:myImage ><br>" & "Did you get this image?!?!?!" & "</body></html>", Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)`

Comment: Problem solved.  I was missing image content type declaration on the AlternateView.

Answer (score 0):

I am opening the email on several platforms including Outlook and various web mail products with the same results.  I read that I may be missing something in my email message headers.  I am going pursue that route and see if that fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

There's a "Send pictures with document" registry value which allows (or not) embedded images. Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Options